# c# Fluent Builder and invalid object state

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, dsl

I have a question about Fluent Interface Builder. 
I have a simple object like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    ... other properties
}
```

and I have a simple UserBuilder class:

```
public class UserBuilder
{
    private string _name;
    private string _surname;
    private int _age;
    private Gender _gender;

    private UserBuilder(){ }

    public static UserBuilder Create()
    {
        return new UserBuilder();
    }

    public UserBuilder WithName(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public UserBuilder WithSurname(string surname)
    {
        _surname = surname;
        return this;
    }
    //Other methods......

    public Person Build()
    {
        return new Person
        {
            Name = _name,
            Age = _age,
            Surname = _surname
            ......
        };
    }
}
```

My questions are:
Is it correct to check the status of the object in the build method?
Example:

```
public Person Build()
{
    // Is it correct??
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name))
        throw new Exception();

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_surname))
        throw new Exception();

    return new Person
    {
        Name = _name,
        Age = _age,
        Surname = _surname
        ......
    };
}
```

If it's correct what kind of exception should I throw?
ArgumentException?? InvalidOperationException??
If it's not correct, where and how I can validate object created? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend following the [fail fast principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast), so those checks should be in the "setter" methods, eg:

```
public UserBuilder WithName(string name)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(name));

    _name = name;
    return this;
}
```

`Build` should then just create the `Person` object.

Another point is that, if you are going to go to the trouble of providing a builder, then make `Person` immutable:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, string surname, int age)
        => (Name, Surname, Age) = (name, surname, age);

    public string Name { get; }
    public string Surname { get;}
    public int Age { get; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't `Build()` part of the same call chain anyway?  I like that tuple assignment arrangement; I didn't know you could do that in C#.

Comment: In fact, if I avoid calling a method of the chain I could mistakenly set a parameter to null when I call the build method, unless in the constructor of the user object it does not perform the verification on the parameters again

Comment: I found this solution that seems a good work. Thanks anyway  [Advances in Applying the Builder Design Pattern](http://codinghelmet.com/articles/advances-in-applying-the-builder-design-pattern)